# Ubuntu + Raid on HP proliant DL 160 G6

Tags: bios, raid, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-8.04

I'm trying to install [Ubuntu 8.04 Server](http://releases.ubuntu.com/hardy/) on an [HP Proliant DL160 G6](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/15351-15351-3328412-241644-3328421-3884343.html). The HP hardware is [certified by Ubuntu for the 9.04 version](http://www.ubuntu.com/partners/hp), which I can't install due to company policy.

The problem is that Ubuntu would not recognize the RAID 1+0 disk configured by the BIOS. The raid creates one ~470GB disk from two 500GB physical disks.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We gave up, and chose [Ubuntu's software RAID](http://kuparinen.org/martti/comp/ubuntu/en/raid.html) instead of Hardware\BIOS Raid, which works fine - but still, A hardware solution would be nice for the rest of the world.

By the way, in order to make the network interfaces work we had to download and install new kernels from the [Ubuntu kernel repository](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

Comment: I don't think you'll see that much degradation in performance from the software RAID as opposed to the hardware (I don't on my machines, anyway).

As for the hardware, I'd recommend at least an DL360 or better next time. For some reason the hardware in those seems to be better supported across OS's.

Comment: +1 thanks for the advice. Care to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu doesn't see the hardware raid because it probably doesn't have a kernel driver for the raid card. You need to find the exact make/model of the raid card (you can usually see this flash by during early boot up, before grub takes over) and see if you can get a kernel module our source for the driver.

Comment: it appears (according to the mfg's specs webpage) to be "HP Smart Array B110i".  there's [some indication it is fakeRAID](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/raid-array-not-detected-new-hp-ml150g6-server-739130/page2.html) but i can't confirm that.  there's also indication that hp makes a Linux driver for it.